# getopt-like behavior in Go

Tags: go

How do I nicely parse a list of program parameters and automate handling "--help" and/or "--version" (such as "`program [-d value] [--abc] [FILE1]`") in Go?

Comment: 2019: `github.com/rsc/getopt` seems a simple alternative: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750119/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it just for you:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt";
  "os"
)

func main() {
  for i, arg := range os.Args {
    if arg == "-help" {
      fmt.Printf ("I need somebody\n")
    }else if arg == "-version" {
      fmt.Printf ("Version Zero\n")
    } else {
      fmt.Printf("arg %d: %s\n", i, os.Args[i])
    }
  }
}
```

see also https://play.golang.org/p/XtNXG-DhLI

Test:

```
$ ./8.out -help -version monkey business
I need somebody
Version Zero
arg 3: monkey
arg 4: business
```

Comment: This code doesn't support flag arguments (like the OP's `-d value`) or defaults; and if the programmer rolls their own, they're unlikely to meet user expectations (like equivalence of `--key value` and `--key=value`).  Hand-rolled --help makes it hard to generate tab-completion, and requires manual maintenance of spatially disparate code.  Real code probably ought to partition Args into flags and their values on one hand, and non-flag args on the other.  When a newcomer asks for guidance on something as tricky yet fundamental as argument parsing, the correct answer is not "roll your own."

Answer (score 24):

Google has created a [getopt](https://godoc.org/github.com/pborman/getopt) package (`import "github.com/pborman/getopt"`) which provides the more standard command line parsing (vs the 'flag' package).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/pborman/getopt"
)

func main() {
    optName := getopt.StringLong("name", 'n', "", "Your name")
    optHelp := getopt.BoolLong("help", 0, "Help")
    getopt.Parse()

    if *optHelp {
        getopt.Usage()
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    fmt.Println("Hello " + *optName + "!")
}
```

```
$ ./hello --help
Usage: hello [--help] [-n value] [parameters ...]
     --help        Help
 -n, --name=value  Your name

$ ./hello --name Bob
Hello Bob!
```

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. The package was written by Googler and Google owns the copyright.

Comment: Newbie question - does this interfere with positional args? I'm assuming not. I need to do some more reading.

Answer (score 15):

Use the 'flag' package: http://golang.org/pkg/flag/. It doesn't do double-dash arguments, however. There isn't anything that exactly mimics GNU getopt behaviour (yet.)

Comment: About time someone wrote one. It's been out for a whole day now.

Comment: @Kinopiko: Take a look at go-mode.el in the misc/emacs directory of the source code repo.

Comment: Here is a link to an example that uses command line flags: http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html#tmp_53 (The "Echo" example on the Go tutorial)

Answer (score 10):

From the section "Command Line UI", you have several libraries able to parse [getopt-long parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html#Argument-Syntax).

I tried, with a Go1.0.2:

- the [code.google.com/p/opts-go](http://code.google.com/p/opts-go/) (See [its documentation](http://go.pkgdoc.org/code.google.com/p/opts-go)), which isn't quite operational.
- the [github.com/droundy/goopt](https://github.com/droundy/goopt) (See [its documentation](http://go.pkgdoc.org/github.com/droundy/goopt)), which has a [complete set of examples](https://github.com/droundy/goopt/blob/master/example/example.go).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    goopt "github.com/droundy/goopt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("flag")
    goopt.NoArg([]string{"--abc"}, "abc param, no value", noabc)

    goopt.Description = func() string {
        return "Example program for using the goopt flag library."
    }
    goopt.Version = "1.0"
    goopt.Summary = "goopt demonstration program"
    goopt.Parse(nil)
}

func noabc() error {
    fmt.Println("You should have an --abc parameter")
    return nil
}
```

Other default parameters provided with `goopt`:

```
 --help               Display the generated help message (calls Help())
 --create-manpage     Display a manpage generated by the goopt library (uses Author, Suite, etc)
 --list-options       List all known flags
```

Answer (score 7):

[go-flags](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags) is very complete, BSD licensed, and has a clear [example](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags/blob/master/example_test.go).

```
var opts struct {
      DSomething string `short:"d" description:"Whatever this is" required:"true"`
      ABC bool `long:"abc" description:"Something"`
}

fileArgs, err := flags.Parse(&opts)

if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Comment: go-flags is quite complete and also has subcommand feature that I want. But document is hard to understand. I suggest reading example code + refering to its doc would be the best. (The example link you pointed to is very useful.)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is [Kingping](https://github.com/alecthomas/kingpin) which provides support for all the standard goodies you have come to expect from a modern command line parsing library. It has `--help` in multiple formats, sub-commands, requirements, types, defaults, etc. It's also still under development. It seems like the other suggestions here haven't been updated in a while.

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "strings"
  "gopkg.in/alecthomas/kingpin.v2"
)

var (
  app      = kingpin.New("chat", "A command-line chat application.")
  debug    = app.Flag("debug", "Enable debug mode.").Bool()
  serverIP = app.Flag("server", "Server address.").Default("127.0.0.1").IP()

  register     = app.Command("register", "Register a new user.")
  registerNick = register.Arg("nick", "Nickname for user.").Required().String()
  registerName = register.Arg("name", "Name of user.").Required().String()

  post        = app.Command("post", "Post a message to a channel.")
  postImage   = post.Flag("image", "Image to post.").File()
  postChannel = post.Arg("channel", "Channel to post to.").Required().String()
  postText    = post.Arg("text", "Text to post.").Strings()
)

func main() {
  switch kingpin.MustParse(app.Parse(os.Args[1:])) {
  // Register user
  case register.FullCommand():
    println(*registerNick)

  // Post message
  case post.FullCommand():
    if *postImage != nil {
    }
    text := strings.Join(*postText, " ")
    println("Post:", text)
  }
}
```

And the `--help` output:

```
$ chat --help
usage: chat [<flags>] <command> [<flags>] [<args> ...]

A command-line chat application.

Flags:
  --help              Show help.
  --debug             Enable debug mode.
  --server=127.0.0.1  Server address.

Commands:
  help [<command>]
    Show help for a command.

  register <nick> <name>
    Register a new user.

  post [<flags>] <channel> [<text>]
    Post a message to a channel.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is docopt. I'll just refer you [to an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20086311/13760) I posted for the details.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple library, you have since August 2017 [**`github.com/rsc/getopt`**](https://github.com/rsc/getopt)

> To use, define flags as usual with package flag. Then introduce any aliases by calling `getopt.Alias`:

```
getopt.Alias("v", "verbose")
```

> Or call `getopt.Aliases` to define a list of aliases:

```
getopt.Aliases(
    "v", "verbose",
    "x", "xylophone",
)
```

And:

> In general Go flag parsing is preferred for new programs, because it is not as pedantic about the number of dashes used to invoke a flag (you can write `-verbose` or `--verbose`, and the program does not care).
>
> This package is meant to be used in situations where, for legacy reasons, it is important to use exactly **[`getopt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)** syntax, such as when rewriting in Go an existing tool that already uses `getopt(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use Golang own library "flag".

It has pretty much code to create CLI like application in GoLang. for Example :

```
srcDir := flag.String("srcDir", "", "Source directory of the input csv file.")
```

The above String method of flag library will expect one argument from command prompt.

Go to https://golang.org/pkg/flag/ for more reading.

Happy Learning...