# How to access command-line arguments passed to a Go program?

Tags: go

How do I access command-line arguments in Go? They're not passed as arguments to `main`.

> A complete program, possibly created by linking multiple packages, must have one package called main, with a function
>
> ```
> func main() { ... }
> ```
>
> defined. The function main.main() takes no arguments and returns no value.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can access the command-line arguments using the [`os.Args`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) variable. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(len(os.Args), os.Args)
}
```

You can also use the [flag package](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/), which implements command-line flag parsing.

Answer (score 27):

[Flag](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags) is a good package for that.

Code example and comments from https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags by [Mark McGranaghan](https://markmcgranaghan.com/) and [Eli Bendersky](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/):

```
package main

// Go provides a `flag` package supporting basic
// command-line flag parsing. We'll use this package to
// implement our example command-line program.
import "flag"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    // Basic flag declarations are available for string,
    // integer, and boolean options. Here we declare a
    // string flag `word` with a default value `"foo"`
    // and a short description. This `flag.String` function
    // returns a string pointer (not a string value);
    // we'll see how to use this pointer below.
    wordPtr := flag.String("word", "foo", "a string")

    // This declares `numb` and `fork` flags, using a
    // similar approach to the `word` flag.
    numbPtr := flag.Int("numb", 42, "an int")
    boolPtr := flag.Bool("fork", false, "a bool")

    // It's also possible to declare an option that uses an
    // existing var declared elsewhere in the program.
    // Note that we need to pass in a pointer to the flag
    // declaration function.
    var svar string
    flag.StringVar(&svar, "svar", "bar", "a string var")

    // Once all flags are declared, call `flag.Parse()`
    // to execute the command-line parsing.
    flag.Parse()

    // Here we'll just dump out the parsed options and
    // any trailing positional arguments. Note that we
    // need to dereference the pointers with e.g. `*wordPtr`
    // to get the actual option values.
    fmt.Println("word:", *wordPtr)
    fmt.Println("numb:", *numbPtr)
    fmt.Println("fork:", *boolPtr)
    fmt.Println("svar:", svar)
    fmt.Println("tail:", flag.Args())
}
```

Answer (score 19):

**Quick Answer:**

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "os"
)

func main() {
    argsWithProg := os.Args
    argsWithoutProg := os.Args[1:]
    arg := os.Args[3]
    fmt.Println(argsWithProg)
    fmt.Println(argsWithoutProg)
    fmt.Println(arg)
}
```

Test: `$ go run test.go 1 2 3 4 5`

**Out:**

```
[/tmp/go-build162373819/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/modbus 1 2 3 4 5]
[1 2 3 4 5]
3
```

> **NOTE**: `os.Args` provides access to raw command-line arguments. Note that the first value in this slice is the path to the program,
>   and `os.Args[1:]` holds the arguments to the program.
>   [Reference](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 11):

Command line arguments can be found in [os.Args](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables). In most cases though the package [flag](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) is better because it does the argument parsing for you.

Answer (score 8):

Peter's answer is exactly what you need if you just want a list of arguments.

However, if you're looking for functionality similar to that present on UNIX, then you could use the [go implementation](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.go) of [docopt](http://docopt.org/). You can try it [here](http://try.docopt.org/).

docopt will return JSON that you can then process to your heart's content.